# The different between Points for daily visits and for login

Tags: wordpress, plugins, hook, point

There are two hooks in myCRED WordPress plugin, points for daily visits and points for login. I do not understand what is the different between them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Points for Daily Visits**
>
> This hook allows you to award or deduct points from your users for
> visiting your website. This hook was built to award points maximum
> once a day irrelevant from which page a user visits.
>
> **Points for Logging In**
>
> This hook allows you to award or deduct points from your users for
> logging in to your website. To prevent abuse, you can set an optional
> daily limit.

From [Hooks myCRED](http://mycred.me/hooks/)

Answer (score 0):

Daily visit does not require user to login unlike the logging in hook